# Another expression for "I remember"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there another expression for "I remember something" which sounds more like a native speaker or advanced-level English learner?

For example, something happened before and someone checks with me whether I know that thing. Would I say "I remember that" or some other better native expression?

Comment: One can say 'I recall'. But the meaning is slightly different, sometimes misused by people who lie 'I don't recall' ; their meaning being 'I refuse to think about it.Memory and recall are slightly different things.

Answer (score 2):

"From what I recall..."

[Recall](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/recall) means "to bring back from memory; recollect; remember"; 
 something I knew or learned in the past and I can find in my memory now.

Synonyms for remember:
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/remember